# Should I cross-compile in Linux or Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, qt, cross-compiling

To create a `.exe` in Linux using Qt SDK, should I cross compile my application in Linux or cross-compile my application in Windows?

Comment: I remember you posting questions about cross-compiling Qt applications, few days back. I still have not been able to get it to work for myself. :-(

Comment: You have 5 questions about exact same topic already, why can't you just stick with the single question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cross compile **on** Linux, **for** windows.

EDIT:

1. install MinGW on **Linux**.
2. **cross-compile** your Qt code on **Linux**. A windows binary (**.exe**) should be produced.
3. You are done. Happily execute the exe on any windows system with Qt runtime libraries.

Hope that clears things up.

jrh

Comment: i have refered to the link which u gave me before  
http://silmor.de/29.  , but its confusing me a bit:(
so pls give me clear picture of wat to be done!!!! ... 
pls reply

Answer (score 4):

Either **cross-compile** in Linux, or **compile** in Windows.

Comment: You have to install MingW in Linux, for cross-compiling.

Comment: ok.. thanks a lots..
by installing QT SDK and MingW in Linux,is it able to get .exe for windows.. pls do tel me what else should i install in Linux to generate .exe????

Comment: Sorry to say, but I have not yet been able to set up my cross-compiling environment. So, I am out of answers. :-(

Answer (score 2):

First off, kvg. Google search for "cross-compiling qt applications in linux for windows" and first link that comes up is this: [http://silmor.de/29](https://web.archive.org/web/20100212034856/http://silmor.de/29)

The steps should be simple:

- install mingw
- install qt linux binaries so that you get qmake and moc and other stuff needed for compilation.
- get *windows* qt binaries and other possible libraries your application requires.
- create a new qmake configuration files (see silmor.de page for more details)
- go to your source folder and call qmake -spec $SpecFileCreatedInStep4
- make
- profit!!
- close your questions in so.