# How to compile for Windows if I am under Linux?

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross compile in Linux or Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025687/cross-compile-in-linux-or-windows)

Does this involve the mkspecs?

Comment: no, the thing is that i just wanted to know if i can make a .exe from my linux Qt

Comment: for example in linux if i go at projects->buil-> mkspecs is linux g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This may help](http://www.limitlessfx.com/using-cmake-mingw-to-cross-compile-windows-apps.html) This is cross-compiling and if I were you I'd simply recompile *in Windows* to keep things simple.

General advice: keep your source code *and build chain* as platform-independent as possible. CMake will help you stay honest here.

When on Linux, CMake will generate a Makefile environment.

If you take the exact same source tree into Windows, CMake will generate a Visual Studio project.

Comment: thank you spraff for the help,  but still i ll wait to find out if there really isn`t sth easier

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's not really recommended for the good reasons above. @spraff has actually answered the question with his link, so you need to read up on that, but no it's not really about the mkspecs, it's about having an actual compiler on your machine that creates Windows executable binaries. The mkspecs are there to tell Qt what compiler to use and how to use it, they don't do the actual compilation process.

Comment: so there isn`t something more easy to do?

Comment: Not really, I sank about a full 3 days of work into trying to get a stable cross compile toolchain working and gave up, it was easier just to compile it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is [mingw-cross-env](http://mingw-cross-env.nongnu.org/).