# Qt - Cross-compiling on Windows for Linux

Tags: windows, linux, qt, cross-compiling

I fail to find any instructions on how to cross-compile a Qt app for linux on the windows platform. So could someone give me or link me to step-by-step instructions on how to do so.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025687/cross-compile-in-linux-or-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install distcc on your Linux machine. Choose one of the distcc compilers as the compiler Qt will use in the projects pane of Qt Creator. Setup the hosts file for distcc to point at your Windows machine and specify the number of jobs you want to send to it.

On the Windows machine, you have two options - get VirtualBox, and put the same Linux OS on that, or use Cygwin. With either of those options, you can install distcc and get it to listen for incoming tasks from your Linux machine.